# Are there disadvantages when running a docker base image that differs from my distribution?

Tags: linux, docker

My understanding is, that a docker image shares the boot file system with the host and tries to share as much as possible of the root file system.

What if I run an ubuntu base image on a current arch? They not only differ by means of the root fs (e.g. systemd vs upstart) but also the boot fs (e.g. kernel 3.5 vs 3.12). Does the ubuntu image spin up its own kernel in that case?

What if I run an ubuntu image on ubuntu?

Should I expect:

1. Better performance?
2. Smaller image sizes?
3. Lower memory footprint?
4. Is there a lower probability of crashes or bugs?

If any of those apply: is the silver bullet to create your own base image for the intended environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker shares just **kernel** with the host system. It does not spin a new kernel. The complete filesystem is stored in a docker image. You can run just one process in container, not full system (e.q. not running upstart in ubuntu).

I recommend to read this answer related to performance/memory/disk footprint, it explains a lot:

[What is the impact of using multiple Base Images in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18601640/what-is-the-impact-of-using-multiple-base-images-in-docker/18923338#18923338)